# Copy from MS Word document to a web page input box

Tags: vba, ms-word

In an already open word document select all text
copy selected text to clipboard
check default browser open at correct web address
    if not open default browser at web address "http://thisaddress.com"
give focus to browser
paste clipboard text into input box called "input1"

or some other way to get MSword document contents to a web page input?

Currently the workflow involves a secretary logging in to the website, then filling out a web form, switching to their open MS Word document, selecting all, copying the WP document, then back to the web form and pasting into an input box, then hitting submit. What I want to do ideally have a button in MS word which opens the browser to the correct web page then copies and pastes the document into the correct input box on the page (in fact it will be the only textarea form field).

The MS Word VBA code is:

```
Option Explicit

Enum W32_Window_State
    Show_Normal = 1
    Show_Minimized = 2
    Show_Maximized = 3
    Show_Min_No_Active = 7
    Show_Default = 10
End Enum

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Function OpenURL(URL As String, WindowState As W32_Window_State) As Boolean

' Opens passed URL with default application, or Error Code (<32) upon error

    Dim lngHWnd As Long
    Dim lngReturn As Long

    lngReturn = ShellExecute(lngHWnd, "open", URL, vbNullString, _
        vbNullString, WindowState)

    OpenURL = (lngReturn > 32)
End Function

Sub TestMacro()
  Application.ActiveDocument.Select
  Selection.Copy
  OpenURL "http://localhost:8500/index.cfm?wordContent=" & Selection, W32_Window_State.Show_Maximized
End Sub
```

and in the coldfusion handling form

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
    <Textarea ID="txtArea" rows=6><cfoutput>#url.wordContent#</cfoutput></textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Just would like to work out how to not open a new browser window if one is already open.

Comment: What is the web form address?

Comment: Is the web-application part of your solution? can you modify it ?

Comment: I updated my answer with further clues, check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you can modify the web-application, you may do the following:

1. MS-Word: Copy content to clipboard.
2. MS-Word: Open Url as "http://thisaddress.com/SomePage?pasteClipboard=true"
3. SomePage: if query-string param pasteClipboard == true, then add a javascript function to get the clipboard data into your form field.

**Update:**

In your macro you simply call `Selection.Copy`, and to open the URL using default browser check this link http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_23225744.html

Using the code from the previous link, I made a test macro as :

```
Sub TestMacro()
  Application.ActiveDocument.Select
  Selection.Copy
  OpenURL  "http://thisaddress.com/SomePage?pasteClipboard=true", W32_Window_State.Show_Maximized
End Sub
```

I hope this was helpful.

**Update 2:**

Just use `W32_Window_State.Show_Default`, Here is the full macro:

```
Option Explicit

Enum W32_Window_State
    Show_Normal = 1
    Show_Minimized = 2
    Show_Maximized = 3
    Show_Min_No_Active = 7
    Show_Default = 10
End Enum

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Function OpenURL(URL As String, WindowState As W32_Window_State) As Boolean

' Opens passed URL with default application, or Error Code (<32) upon error

    Dim lngHWnd As Long
    Dim lngReturn As Long

    lngReturn = ShellExecute(lngHWnd, "open", URL, vbNullString, _
        vbNullString, WindowState)

    OpenURL = (lngReturn > 32)
End Function

Sub TestMacro()
  Application.ActiveDocument.Select
  Selection.Copy
  OpenURL "http://thisaddress.com/SomePage?pasteClipboard=true", W32_Window_State.Show_Default
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the web app is under my control. Any further clues to 1 and 2 please?

Comment: Very nearly there, and thanks for your help. This opens a new browser window each time. Is there a way of modifying this so that a new browser is opened only if the browser is not already open.

Comment: I think W32_Window_State.Show_Default is what you are looking for, any way I updated the answer with the complete macro code.

Comment: I tested all the W32_Window_State options but they unfortunately all open a new browser window. I don't know enough to be able to amend the function to check if a browser window already open and if so just go to the URL

Comment: When I used W32_Window_State.Show_Default the url was opened in the same IE browser window but in a different tab, going to [Tools>Internet Options>Tabs>Settings>Open links from other programs in:(The current tab or window)] made it open in the current tab, also there is another option in [Tools>Internet Options>Advanced>Settings>Resue windows for launching shortcuts (when tabbed browsing is off)].

The bottom line is, using shell execute is just a starting point - the rest is up to the target application (the browser in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look into controlling Internet Explorer from inside Word using a control.

[Here](http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/4623.html) is an example.

Note, this will only work with IE (unless there are dll versions of Firefox etc.)